# Can you figure out why section 2 is going behind the video?

Tags: html, css

Section 2 is going behind my video background. Resizing the browser messes everything up.

I really don't know CSS, so?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <script src="Assets/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- The video -->
    <video autoplay muted id="myVideo">
        <source src="Images/banner.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <div class="content">

        <h1>
            <a href=""
               class="typewrite"
               data-period="1800"
               data-type='["hi", "I'm james", "I am creative", "I enjoy designing stuff", ""]'>

                <span class="wrap"></span>
            </a>
        </h1>

        <a href="#section2">"*"</a>
     </div>

     <div>
         <h2 id="section2"> Section 2 <br> jb <br> jb <br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb</h2>
     </div>
</body>
```

I have it so some text types out a few small sentences over a video.

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  /* padding-top: 10em; */
}
* {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'CustomFont';
    font-weight: 80;
    font-size: 80px;
}

#slide {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

/* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */
#myVideo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 800;
  font-family: 'CustomFont';
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  color: #F1F1F1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The video tag is on top of other elements by default, and you can send it to back by:

```
#myVideo {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  /* padding-top: 10em; */
}

* {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'CustomFont';
  font-weight: 80;
  font-size: 80px;
}

#slide {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}


/* Style the video: 100% width and height to cover the entire window */

#myVideo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Add some content at the bottom of the video/page */

.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 800;
  font-family: 'CustomFont';
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

#myVideo {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="Assets/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- The video -->
<video autoplay muted id="myVideo">
   <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="content">
  <h1>
    <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="1800" data-type='[ "Hi", "I'm james", "I am creative", "I enjoy designing stuff", "" ]'>
      <span class="wrap"></span>
    </a>
  </h1>
  <a href="#section2"> "*" </a>
</div>

<div>
  <h2 id="section2"> Section 2 <br> jb <br> jb <br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb<br> jb</h2>
</div>
```

You can also see it [here](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/KKPXeRo?editors=1100).